# Cron stopped working after I added another job

Tags: cron, ubuntu-14.04

I hope you're doing well.

I am facing a big problem with my cron jobs. Up until today I had two cron jobs to be run in my crontab to be ran at specific times of the day.

Everything ran flawlessly until I added another one, now no cron is running. Even erasing the newly added job didn't fix the issue.

Why did this happen? Can you please help me? Thanks!

Crons for your review:

```
0  18   * * 1-5 root    cd /var/www/html/require/ && php correoTodosComprobantesHoy.php > ../debug/get_debug_correo_hoy.txt &
0  */2  * * *   root    cd /var/www/html/default/ && php correosDiarios.php > ../debug/get_debug_correos_clientes.txt &
30  18   * * 1-5 root   cd /var/www/html/require/ && php correoTodosEscaneosHoy.php > ../debug/get_debug.txt &
```

Comment: Have you checked the log for `cron`?

Comment: I have just checked it and there is no record of the job running at the time it should be

Comment: Check `/var/log/messages`. Look for entries referencing the jobs not running.

Comment: @NasirRiley I can't find the file you mentioned :(

Comment: Your system doesn't have `/var/log/messages`???? If that's the case then you've got bigger problems. That log contains messages regarding cron jobs and many other things.

Comment: What can I do in that case? :o

Comment: I didn't mean to scare you there as it may not necessarily be the end of the world. You can check `syslog` or `rsyslog` to see where your system is sending the logs for `cron`. Normally it would send them to `/var/log/messages` but it's possible that they are being sent elsewhere.

Comment: but, I saw that the cron jobs were sent to syslog. Can it change?

Comment: Check `syslog` for any references to the cron jobs not running such as errors.

Comment: I saw this error: 
Jul 27 16:22:01 milybro cron[1387]: (*system*) ERROR (Missing newline before EOF, this crontab file will be ignored)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That makes sense. I didn't notice it before but you need to add a newline after your last job in `cron`

Comment: I was not aware this made a difference! Do I need to add is as unicode <\n> or just hit enter?

Comment: You can just hit enter. That's always worked for me across many different environments. It's also something that I sometimes forget.

Comment: @Julio Garcia You are welcome. Glad to help.